# Merge multiple WP_Query results into an array with no duplicates

Tags: wordpress, array-merge

I have a custom post type with its own custom template, and I want to display blog posts that are related to the custom post type title. However, I want to display a referenced post first, then search for any posts with tags, and then find relevant posts after that. Any one of these could result in no results or many. The total number of posts I want to display is 6.

`

```
$searchtag = strtolower(get_the_title());

$arg1 = array(
    'post_type'   => 'post',
    'p' => $post_id,
);
$arg2 = array(
    'post_type'   => 'post',
    'tag' => $searchtag,
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'orderby' => 'post_date',
    'order' => 'desc',
    'posts_per_page' => 6,
);
$arg3 = array(
    'post_type'   => 'post',
    's' => $searchtag,
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'orderby' => 'relevance',
    'posts_per_page' => 6,
);

// Get the posts
$query1 = new wp_query( $arg1 );
$query2 = new wp_query( $arg2 );
$query3 = new wp_query( $arg3 );
$related_query = new wp_query(); 

// Merge the unique posts
$related_query->posts = array_merge($query1->posts, $query2->posts, $query3->posts);
$related_query->post_count = $query1->post_count + $query2->post_count + $query3->post_count;

if($related_query->have_posts):
```

`

I read an article that stated that using post__not_in was taxing on the database and I should not incorporate it.

1. Do I need to add logic if the query->post_count = 0?
2. How can I maintain the order but ensure that there are no duplicates displayed?

I get duplicates in these results currently. I'd like to eliminate them while keeping the order of the posts by query1, then query2 then query3... displaying the first 6 posts.

Comment: If you have 1000s of posts, `post__not_in` might be taxing, but if not, you can use it. Why not merge all of your `$args` into a single array? This seems like overkill for what you actually want. However, if you want to keep what you have, you can simply do an `else :` after the `if` statement to catch if there are no posts returned. For number 2, use [array_unique](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php). Setup a variable `$merged_posts = array_merge(all your queries here)` and then use `array_unique` to get the unique posts.

Comment: I did try to use array_unique and I was getting some kind of Stack trace error - `Uncaught Error: Object of class WP_Post could not be converted to string in` and the page wouldn't load.

Comment: args doesn't allow for multiple order and orderby statements as far as the documentation shows. I need the first to be a post_id that I specify, then followed by any posts tagged with the term (date, desc)... then followed by any relevant terms (asc).

Comment: The error is self explanatory: you are passing an object to an array. You need to only pass the ID of the post. You can certainly use multiple `orderby` statements. You separate the orderby using spaces `'orderby' => 'title date etc'`. There is a much better way to get what you want here. Look at the answer below using `get_posts`. You can use the same `$args` you have and pass those to `get_posts` instead. Then you have all the post objects and you can get the `ID` property to pass into the array_merge/array_unique

Answer (score 1):

The better way is make 3 queries with parameter:

```
'fields' => 'ids'
```

and there:

```
$postIds1 = get_posts($args1);
```

when merge got data:

```
$postIds = array_merge(array(0), $postIds1, $postIds2, $postIds3);
```

and when make forth request with

```
'post__in' => $postIds
```